# Reduce size of indentation between cascading itemize and enumerate environments

Tags: itemize

How can I reduce the size of the indentation between cascading itemize and enumerate environments ?

```
\begin{itemize}
\item 
  \begin{itemize}
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
  \end{itemize}
\item 
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to an MWE (Minimal Working Example) a complete small document with your list which we can test as it is. In MWE's preamble should be only be load to your problem relevant packages.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The `\itemsep` length adjusts this; for example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}\itemsep=0pt
\item Hello
  \begin{itemize}\itemsep=0pt
  \item  One
  \item  Two
  \item  Three
  \end{itemize}
\item Bye
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

However, if you want to adjust such parameters for *all* lists, not just the current one, or want to do other things to the list as well, you might consider using the `enumitem` package.